# GCC: No such file or directory

Tags: c, batch-file, lib

I made a fresh project and have been stuck in this specific issue for hours. I am using a shell script (.bat) file to compile and build the project. If I use no libraries, it compiles and runs fine. However, when I try to add SDL2 I get the issues described in the title. I was using Visual Studio Code, set up everything correctly in tasks.json and the issue persisted. I moved to 4code and the issue remains.

This is my build.bat

```
@echo off
if not exist build mkdir build
pushd build
gcc ..\source\main.c -o main.exe
gcc -L ..\external\SDL2\include
popd
```

I added the library in the "external" folder. It tells me it can't find the **SDL.h** file. I am confused because the file is in ..\external\SDL2\include

I never coded in C, so all this compiler business is new to me. I've searched the web for hours and can't find a solution. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: The first thing you should do, before anything else, is to begin your batch file by determining that your current working directory is known. Currently you're just assuming it! The best way to do that, in this case is to be sure that you can make that relative to `\source\main.c` and/or `\external\SDL2\include`, or better `\external\SDL2\include\sdl.h`. This would certainly be more efficient that creating a possibly missing directory and then finding out that your working directory was incorrect from the outset later.

Answer (score 2):

Directory-adding options must be used with compilation command.

`gcc ..\source\main.c -o main.exe` is a compilation command without directory adding
and `gcc -lSDL2` and `gcc -L ..\external\SDL2\include` are not compilation commands
because they don't include what to compile.

The 3 `gcc` invokations should be one invokation:

```
gcc -L ..\external\SDL2\include ..\source\main.c -o main.exe -lSDL2
```

Comment: Thank you! I have done as you described and the issue persists.
"..\source\main.c:1:10: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory"
I'm clueless. Logic says it's an issue with the directory but everything is correct.